# HTML/CSS Floating an img beside paragraphs and unordered lists

Tags: html, css, css-float

I've seen similar questions on here but none of the solutions given helped me.
I'm trying to float an <img> beside a grouping of a <p>, a <ul> and another <p>
here's what the tags look like

```
<p></p>
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<p></p>
<img src="" alt="" />
```

So all I need is for the <img> to be beside all three of the other tags.
I imagine there's a really obvious solution to this that I'm missing.

Comment: And where is the CSS that you have used to try floating the image? Also "*<img> to be beside all three of the other tags*"... beside, how? To the left or the right?

Comment: The `<img>` tag does not use or need a closing slash.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you are trying to float the image to either the right or the left, the current 2 answers will not put the image beside the text - they will only float the image to the right *underneath* the text.

**Example when you *only* float the image - it doesn't work :)**

```css
img { 
    float:right;
    /* styling to show a "placeholder" for the image so you can see where it would appear */
    width:100px; height:100px; background:#ccc; 
}
```

```html
<p>paragraph</p>
    <ul>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
    <p>paragraph</p>
<img src="" alt="" class="" />
```

There are 2 ways you can do this, depending on whether you have control over the HTML or not.

1. **Move the image to before the text and then float it**

If you can change the html, you need to move the image before the text so that the text can them fill the space that remains after the image is floated, e.g.

```css
img { 
    float:right;
    /* styling to show a "placeholder" for the image so you can see where it would appear */
    width:100px; height:100px; background:#ccc; 
}
```

```html
<img src="" alt="" />
<p>paragraph</p>
    <ul>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
    <p>paragraph</p>
```

2. **Float the text to the left and the image to the right**

```css
img { 
    float:right;
    /* styling to show a "placeholder" for the image so you can see where it would appear */
    width:100px; height:100px; background:#ccc; 
}

.text { float:left;}
```

```html
<div class="text">
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <ul>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
    <p>paragraph</p>
</div>
<img  style="float: right" alt="" />
```

However be aware that this will cause more issues, because when you float elements, it takes them out of the flow, and taking both out of the flow gets even more complicated.

**Using Clearfix**

One option is to use clearfix to make the the content that comes after the floats "clear" them - see this snippet for examples of what happens with and without clearfix.

```css
img { 
    float:right;
    /* styling to show a "placeholder" for the image so you can see where it would appear */
    width:100px; height:100px; background:#ccc; 
}

.text { float:left;}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

hr { clear:both;}
```

```html
<h3>Without Clearfix</h3>
<div class="text">
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <ul>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
    <p>paragraph</p>
</div>
<img style="float: right" alt="" />
<p><b>This is content after the floats</b></p>

<hr>

<h3>With Clearfix</h3>
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="text">
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <ul>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
    <p>paragraph</p>
</div>
<img style="float: right" alt="" />
</div>
<p><b>This is content after the floats</b></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <img style="float: right" src="" alt"" />
```

Answer (score 0):

add styles to the

```
<style>
  img{
    float:right;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: @inxoy No, this is using internal styles instead of inline - which is actually a better solution as inline styles should be avoided where possible.

Comment: @inxoy What? Your comment doesn't make sense. But whatever you are trying to say, the fact still stands that SuperDeveloper did not copy of your answer. This is such a basic question that all possible answers are going to be a variation on floating the image (as was even mentioned in the title), and this one offers a different - and improved - variation for using styles.

Comment: but what sense does it make to post this as a separate answer (probably farming repu) I'm here at SO to help people getting better and to improve my own skill. and from the educational side it would make muuuuch more sense to comment unter my answer that its possible to achieve this goal not only this way..

Comment: @inxoy Why would they do that? Users on SO offer different answers of their own - they don't collaborate on a single answer to make it perfect ! Besides, neither of your answers are actually correct, nor do they fully meet SO guidelines - code-only answers are discouraged because they don't explain how they fix the problem, See  [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).